# Login screen showing again while accessing profile edit policy after user login in App Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I'm asking this behalf of one mobile/web developer, i have created some custom policies in AD B2C. Now the developer is trying to integrate this with an application. For some reason i have used:

```xml
<DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:1.2.0
</DataUri>
```

as the data uri for signin techinical profile. And content defenition is:

```xml
<ContentDefinition Id="api.localaccount.login">
                <LoadUri>my custom html</LoadUri>
                <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
                <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:1.2.0</DataUri>
                <Metadata>
                    <Item Key="DisplayName">Local Account Login</Item>
                </Metadata>

                <LocalizedResourcesReferences MergeBehavior="Prepend">
                    <LocalizedResourcesReference Language="en" LocalizedResourcesReferenceId="signin_en" />
                    <LocalizedResourcesReference Language="es" LocalizedResourcesReferenceId="signin_es" />
                </LocalizedResourcesReferences>
            </ContentDefinition>
```

Login TP:

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-CustomUserName-WithoutSignup">
                    <DisplayName>Local Account Signin UserName</DisplayName>
                    <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
                    <Metadata>
                        <Item Key="setting.operatingMode">Username</Item>
                        <Item Key="setting.retryLimit">11</Item>
                        <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccount.login</Item>
                        <Item Key="UserMessageIfUserAccountDisabled">You account locked.</Item>      
                        <Item Key="UserMessageIfUserAccountLocked">You've made too many incorrect attempts. Please try again later.</Item>
                        <Item Key="setting.showCancelButton">false</Item>
                        <Item Key="language.button_continue">LOG IN</Item>
                        <Item Key="ServiceThrottled">There are too many requests at this moment. Please wait for some time and try again.</Item>
                    </Metadata>
                    <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
                    <InputClaims>
                        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" />
                    </InputClaims>
                    <OutputClaims>
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" Required="true" />
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" Required="true" />
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="executed-SelfAsserted-Input" DefaultValue="false" />                        
</OutputClaims>
<ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
  <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="CheckUserExist" />
  <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="SendOTP" />
  <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="login-NonInteractive" />
</ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

And my user journey is as follows:

```xml
   <UserJourneys>     
        <UserJourney Id="OnBoarding">
            <OrchestrationSteps>        
                <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsProviderSelection" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.idpselections">
                    <ClaimsProviderSelections>
                        <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
                    </ClaimsProviderSelections>
                </OrchestrationStep>

                <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
                    <ClaimsExchanges>
                        <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-CustomUserName-WithoutSignup" />
                    </ClaimsExchanges>
                </OrchestrationStep>

                <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
                    <ClaimsExchanges>
                        <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
                    </ClaimsExchanges>
                </OrchestrationStep>

                <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
                    <ClaimsExchanges>
                        <ClaimsExchange Id="B2CUserProfileUpdateExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-AccountValueUpdate" />
                    </ClaimsExchanges>
                </OrchestrationStep>

                <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="ClaimsExchange">
                    <ClaimsExchanges>
                        <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadUserWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
                    </ClaimsExchanges>
                </OrchestrationStep>

                <OrchestrationStep Order="6" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
            </OrchestrationSteps>
            <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
        </UserJourney>    
    </UserJourneys>
```

Policy works fine and when he tries to integrate it with replying party app, after user signup profile update journey called (above user journey), but it is showing the login screen again. How can bypass the login after registration? Is this something that we need to with policy?

Edit:

I'm using separate policies for sign in and sign up. After signin journey works as expected, but after signup the login screen comes.

Comment: I have edited the question, edited content is under the "Edit:" text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the starter pack again, you have removed the Session management technical profile reference (SM-AAD) from your sign in page. So during profile edit it won’t get skipped for a signed in user.

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/master/LocalAccounts/TrustFrameworkBase.xml#L687

Comment: Thanks,  I figured it out. I have added the session management TP to my Signup  TP(Write operation). But i have a doubt on that. 

I've two TP( signup) one is to write email as user name and other is phone as user name, for both already have the session management TP and i'm calling them from another TP as validation TP, but this haven't the session management TP. That's why the login re-appeared on profile edit. Now i added the session management to this TP and the profile edit worked fine. Why that, both write operations have the session